# Removing an array element by clicking an HTML <li>

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

So I'm doing a playlist manager for youtube (using the ytb api) and for the graphic part I'm doing, such as youtube has, a list of every thumbnail there is in a given playlist. I use an HTML 'ul' and add every thumbnail as a 'li'. 
Everything is working fine but id like to add a feature so the user could click on one of the thumbnails to remove it from the playlist.

First, let me explain how the important part is coded.

I use an array as a queue to stock every video ID that will be played (this is the playlist) :
 `var queue = []`

And for the thumbnail list I use this function :

```
function refreshThumbnailsQueue() {
    var thumbnailsUl = document.getElementById('thumbnailslist');
    while(thumbnailsUl.firstChild) {
      thumbnailsUl.removeChild(thumbnailsUl.firstChild );
    }
    for (var i = 0; i <= queue.length - 1; i++) {
        var thumbnail = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' + queue[i] + '/maxresdefault.jpg';
        var newLi = document.createElement('li');
        newLi.className = 'thumbnailLi';
        newLi.onclick = function() {
            removeFromQueue();
        }
        var newImg = document.createElement('img');
        newImg.className = 'thumbnailImg';
        newImg.src = thumbnail;
        newLi.appendChild(newImg);
        thumbnailsUl.appendChild(newLi);
    }
}
```

So I'm just removing every child the ul has and then filling it with every thumbnail of the video IDs there are in my queue var.

As you can see, there is a removeFromQueue() function called with an onclick event on each li in the code, and this is what I try to code.
Basicaly, if you click the third li, it should remove the third element of my queue var.

If you have any ideas, please let me know. (and BTW sorry for the mistakes English isn't my main language)

Thanks!

Note : I dont want to use jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Have a look at the javascript array functions for help with what you want to do. the splice call is probably what you need https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If jQuery is an option, you can simply do the following :

```js
$( "li" ).click(function(){
  $( this ).remove();
})
```

As simple as that. If you want more information, I'll update my answer.

---

You can also visit [this page](https://red-team-design.com/removing-an-element-with-plain-javascript-remove-method/) for plain old javascript. Here is the important part :

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

### As for the index of the li element

When you insert the list item in the DOM, you also set it's ID like this :

```js
function refreshThumbnailsQueue() {
    
    ...
    
    for (var i = 0; i <= queue.length - 1; i++) {
        
        ...
        
        // Create the li.
        var newLi = document.createElement('li');
        newLi.id = "song-" + i;
        
        // Create the onclick listening
        li.onclick = function(){
          
          // Remove from DOM.
          var elem = document.getElementById(this.id);
          elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        
          // We keep only the integer (index)
          // In this example, '5' cuts away the "song-".
          var index = parseInt((this.id+"").substring(5));

          // Then, we remove it from the list. 
          YourProgram.removeIndex(index);
        
        }
        
        ...
        
        thumbnailsUl.appendChild(newLi);
    }
}
```

This way, you know what it's index is.

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to mention that I dont wan't to use jQuery :c
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You can also do it in plain javascript. I provided a link in my answer.

Comment: I didn't see it sorry.
I know this method but the thing is I succeded deleting each li by clicking it but it just deleted the li from the dom, not in my queue var. So I can't simply use this method. I need something to find the li position or anything like that to be able to remove it from the dom and from my var.

Comment: One way to do it is to add the index of the <li> to the <li>'s ID on insertion (in the dom). Like so : <li id="song-1">. Then onclick, you take the ID (you parse it) and you retrieve it from the list.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you want that I give the same name to the li id and to the element in the array that matches ?

Comment: Good idea but as the user can add and remove elements from the list, the li indexs will not match the ones in the array right ?

Comment: No problem, keep a counter that increments each time a li is created. that way you will always add more and more elements and there will be no problem with the indexes. You can set your array[index] to null if there is no element in there. But If you want to go that far and keep everything clean, it's more an optimisation problem. It's a problem for another time :)

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to select this as an answer to your question. Have a nice life.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index of the element to remove to the `removeFromQueue()`, like `removeFromQueue(i)`. Then remove the item from `queue`.

```
function removeFromQueue(index) {
  queue.splice(index, 1)
  refreshThumbnailsQueue()
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work, you cant just give the index to the onclick event of the li as it may change if a video is added to the playlist.

Comment: But you are rebuilding the list every time, so yes.